# How to place highcharter objects at same horizontal level using rmarkdown?

Tags: r, highcharts, r-markdown, r-highcharter

I'm using this code to generate 2 highchart objects with rmarkdown:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
---


```{r library_objects, include= FALSE, echo = FALSE}
library(highcharter)
```

```{r objects, include = T, echo = FALSE}
df1 <- data.frame(data = c(2, 4, 6, 10),
                  labels = c("A", "B", "C", "D")
)
df2 <- data.frame(data = c(1, 3, 5, 9),
                  labels = c("Z", "Y", "X", "W")
)
```

```{r charts, include = T, echo = FALSE}
highchart(height = 150, width = 750) %>% 
  hc_add_series(data = df1$data) %>% 
  hc_xAxis(categories = df1$labels)

highchart(height = 150, width = 750) %>% 
  hc_add_series(data = df2$data) %>% 
  hc_xAxis(categories = df2$labels)
```
````

How could I manage to show them at the same horizontal level (one at the left and the other at the right side)?

Answer (score 3):

In highcharter package there is `hw_grid` function.

````
```{r charts, include = T, echo = FALSE}
h1 <- hchart(rnorm(100))
h2 <- hchart(sample(head(letters), size = 100, prob = 1:6, replace = TRUE))

hw_grid(h1, h2)
```
````

There are some other packages to make grid of htmlwidgets like trelliscope. Maybe you want to check them.